# The db2prereqcheck utility could not find the library file libnuma.so.1. on ubi7/ubi:latest docker image

Tags: db2, centos7, numactl, ubi

i have a problem to install numactl-libs (or libnuma.so.1) on a ubi7/ubi:latest Docker image to run the db2 installation.

I have built a Docker image for db2 and wanted to test whether the DB2 installation runs successfully.
However, I get the following error message:

*Requirement not matched for DB2 database "Server" . Version: "11.1.4.6".

Summary of prerequisites that are not met on the current system:

DBT3609E  The db2prereqcheck utility could not find the library file libnuma.so.1.*

The image has ubi7/ubi:latest as base image and the following libraries are also installed as follows:

```
RUN yum install -y libaio numactl-libs libpam.so.0 binutils gcc gcc-c++ ksh numactl && yum clean all
```

All libraries are successfully installed except **numactl-libs** (or **libnuma.so.1**?).

Note: a manual installation of numactl-libs worked without problems and thus the DB2 installation was successful:

```
ADD http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/numactl-libs-2.0.12-5.el7.x86_64.rpm numactl.rpm
RUN rpm -i numactl.rpm
```

However, I would like the installation of numactl-libs to be done automatically with e.g. the command `yum install -y numactl-libs` or another equivalent command.
Unfortunately, an attempt with the command `yum install -y libnuma.so.1` or `yum install -y libnuma.so.*` did not change anything and the same error message was displayed.

Can you please help me? I would be very grateful

Note: in my case a 64-bit version is used.

**Update:**

- Unfortunately even trying to install  `libnuma-dev` and `libnuma1` has not changed anything and the error message is still the same .
- The output of `yum provides libnuma.so.1` is:

> Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos,
> subscription-manager This system is not registered with an
> entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
> No matches found

- It seems that the problem is that `numactl-libs` cannot be installed:
  The output of `yum install numactl-libs` is:

> Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager.
> This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
> No package numactl-libs available.

Comment: What's the output of `yum provides libnuma.so.1`?

Comment: @mao I forgot to mention that I already tried `libnuma-dev` but without success. And just now I tried `libnuma1` but the error message is unfortunately still the same

Comment: @MarkBarinstein the output of `yum provides libnuma.so.1` is:  
_Loaded plugins: ovl, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

No matches found_

Comment: @Brahim suggest you fix the RHN subscription first. See hits on the redhat site for how to resolve this, which you can do if you are a registered developer.

Comment: @mao I will try it out and report again here afterwards.

Comment: you need to install numactl-libs (yum install numactl-libs)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

The problem was fixed and **numactl-libs** could finally be installed:
After I created a Red Hat user account and registered and subscribed to a system for the Red Hat Customer Portal with Red Hat Subscription Manager, numactl-libs installed without any problems.

To register and subscribe to a system for the Red Hat Customer Portal with Red Hat Subscription Manager.
See the following link: (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273)

I added the following line in my Dockerfile before the command `yum install numactl-libs`:
`subscription-manager register --username=[USER_NAME] --password=[PASSWORD] --auto-attach`

After these steps the DB2 installation ran without problems.

Thank you very much for your tips and help!